Inserting an image into multiple OpenOffice.org Calc sheets
how can i Insert an image into the same cell on multiple OpenOffice.org Calc sheets? i've tried setting the image as 'Arrange > To Background', Anchoring 'To Cell & To Page', and just plain Inserting the image, copying the cell and pasting - no go.
